# Implode function PHP

Tags: php

i have a small problem, i'm using a PHP form to get answers off a contact form I created.

Here is the php:

```
$email_message .= "E-Commerce: \n";
$email_message .= (isset($_POST['no-credit'])) ? 
                      "No credit card: $".implode(" ", $_POST['no-credit'])."\n" : '';
$email_message .= (isset($_POST['paypal'])) ? 
                      "Paypal: $".implode(" ", $_POST['paypal'])."\n" : '';
```

When i get the email, and "paypal" or "no credit" is not checked "E-commerce:" still shows up. I tried something like:

```
$email_message .= (isset($_POST['no-credit'])) ? (isset($_POST['paypal'])) ?
                      "E-Commerce: \n";
$email_message .= (isset($_POST['no-credit'])) ? 
                      "No credit card: $".implode(" ", $_POST['no-credit'])."\n" : '';
$email_message .= (isset($_POST['paypal'])) ? 
                      "Paypal: $".implode(" ", $_POST['paypal'])."\n" : '';
```

But it did not work, i fell like i'm not far away but i can not get my hands on it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your condition to `!empty()` also you missing the `:` part in your ternary condition for else part,

```
$email_message .= (!empty($_POST['no-credit']) ) ? 
                      "No credit card: $".implode(" ", $_POST['no-credit'])."\n" : "";
```

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran - Agree. Habitual problem :)

Comment: Removed my comment :) **+1**

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran what about the E-commerce line? i dont get it sorry

Comment: @Rikesh i tried that but No credit card appears in the email even though it's not checked

Comment: `var_dump($_POST['no-credit'])` & check if you getting anything in it.

Answer (score 0):

change your second example like this. But when i tried with my localhost it is working with this code.

```
$email_message .= (!empty($_POST['no-credit'])) ? ((!empty($_POST['paypal'])) ?"E-Commerce: \n":""):""; 
$email_message .= (empty($_POST['no-credit'])) ? 
                      "No credit card: $".implode(" ", $_POST['no-credit'])."\n" : '';
$email_message .= (empty($_POST['paypal'])) ? 
                      "Paypal: $".implode(" ", $_POST['paypal'])."\n" : '';
```